# FIES : food insecurity experience scale package

Tags: r, package, survey

Can someone help me find a package to calculate the FIES score ? I don't seem to find any anywhere.

If there is no package, may someone guide me through the proper equation of the score so I can create a conforming function ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the package. It's called `RM.weights` and it uses the Rasch model to create this score. For more details check the link below :
https://www.fao.org/in-action/voices-of-the-hungry/analyse-data/en/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this link provided by the FAO organisation that includes detailed instructions of how to create this score using the FIES score app designed by the FAO

https://www.fao.org/3/ca9318en/ca9318en.pdf